# React-Native: Doing something when user copies text on clipboard

Tags: android, react-native

I want to build a react-native-app which runs in the background and shows a popup or a Toast whenever the user copies something from any other app.

An example of what I want to achieve:

[image: Screenshot-1]

[image]

So whenever, the user copies some text, as shown in the first screenshot, it should display a dialogue box or show a Toast or maybe just do any action.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, it's not implemented in react native.

> Take a look at [this feature request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18551)!

Comment: Please +1 [this feature request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19759)